# V-For not outputting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm very new to vue.js.

I'm trying to output to a **`v-for`** in the middle of a table on my page, and although there are no errors reported my element is not being rendered.

I know that my data is appearing to the page properly as I can inspect it using the vue.js dev tools.

Could anyone point out what I've gotten wrong please? If anything was reported in the console I could work from there but there's nothing.

**My code is:**

```
<template v-for="item in dashboardData.items">
   <tr>
      <td class="position">{}{item.position}}</td>
      <td>{{item.salespersonname}}</td>
      <td>{{item.units_week1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.weeklytargetform_week1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.targetstreak}}</td>
      <td>£{{item.targetsales}}</td>
      <td>£{{item.actualsales}}</td>
      <td>{{item.points}}</td>
      <td>{{item.performancelevel}}</td>
   </tr>
</template>
```

**and my script is:**

```
<script>
$.get("https://xxxxx.co.uk/reporting/dashboards/team/detailed/week", function(
  data
) {
  var dataItems = data.items;
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#main",
    data: {
      dashboardData: dataItems
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `dashboardData` has an `items` property? You've already pulled out one `items` property with `var dataItems = data.items`, so you're effectively looping over `data.items.items`. Use some console logging to double check.

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right thanks, I'd gone a level too deep !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.items` is already assigned to `dataItems`, so calling `dataItems.items` is a bit like trying to call `data.items.items`. You can fix this a couple of ways, but I'd suggest trying to fix early on to get back up and running...

```
$.get('https://xxxxx.co.uk/reporting/dashboards/team/detailed/week', function(data) {
  var dataItems = data; 
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
      dashboardData: dataItems
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This helped me solve it thanks - I'd gone a level too deep - I'd gotten confused with how the foreach worked. Thank you for the help ! I'm going to go back and hit the tutorials again :)